# Why is the Name column not accessible from the Library Settings with a Document Set?

Tags: content-type, document-set

I have created a custom Content Type called Design Review Document Set, with Document Set as its parent Content Type (and, as usual, Folder as the parent of Document Set).  I added my new Design Review Document Set Content Type to a library, went to Library Settings, and... the Name column, which is required when adding a new item, is not in the Library Settings.  Doesn't even show up.

Looking at the Content Type settings page, I can see that the Name column's source is the Folder content type, and its Type is "File".

I'm trying to figure out this missing column because I want to use it in a workflow.  What I have found so far is that, for a Nintex workflow set to start when an item is modified, modifying the Name column *does not* start the workflow, which suggests that somehow the Name column is "outside" the library itself.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?